# Connecting to LDAP using PEAR LDAP2 in PHP

Tags: php, ldap, pear

I'm not very experienced with using LDAP and have been looking at a few stack overflow questions and tried to piece some code together.

I'm using the PEAR LDAP2 package with my php. So far I have set up my filters, but im not searching for anything yet.

All I am trying to do is set up my connection to the server but when my code reaches:

```
$ldap= Net_LDAP2::connect($config);
```

The script freezes and produces a white screen. How can i fix this?

Script below:

```
<?php

include '../config/connection.php';
require_once '../Scripts/Net_LDAP2-2.0.12/Net/LDAP2/LDAP2.php';

//retrieve information from the form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$usernamefilter = Net_LDAP2_Filter::create('username', 'equals', $username);
$passwordfilter = Net_LDAP2_Filter::create('password', 'equals', $password);
$combinedFilter =  Net_LDAP2_Filter::combine('and', array($usernamefilter, $passwordfilter));

echo "filters have been created. <br />";

// The configuration array:
$config = array (
    'binddn'    => 'username',
    'bindpw'    => 'password',
    'basedn'    => 'ou=People,dc=campus,dc=aston,dc=ac,dc=uk',
    'host'      => 'gc.campus.aston.ac.uk',
'filter'    => $combinedFilter
);

echo "config array has been set up. <br />";

// Connecting using the configuration:
$ldap = Net_LDAP2::connect($config);

echo "connection to ldap has been sent. <br />";

// Testing for connection error
if (PEAR::isError($ldap)) {
    die('Could not connect to LDAP-server: '.$ldap->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider verifying that the LDAP directory server is correctly responding to LDAP client requests by using a known good client. `ldapsearch` as distributed by the vendor is the best choice for this task. Execute the following search to verify that the server is accepting connecting client connections and responding:

```
ldapsearch -h gc.campus.aston.ac.uk -p <your-port> \
   -D the-distinguished-name -w password \
   -b 'ou=People,dc=campus,dc=aston,dc=ac,dc=uk' \
   -s base '(&)' 1.1
```

If this hangs, fails, or returns no entries, correct the problem and re-test until the above command succeeds.

*Note: if you are using the old legacy OpenLDAP ldapsearch, add the -x command line option*